# Small Screw-Turn Potentiometer

Tags: components

I'm new to electronics, and not sure if this exists.

I'm looking to fit a really small potentiometer to vary the resistance on a PCB that lets the user adjust the amount of resistance using a screwdriver.

Does such a component exist? And is there a place where I can look up such information in the future?

Comment: Normally, I'd just look for a "trimpot." Is there something about this that makes these inappropriate for your needs? They come in multiturn and single turn varieties and all kinds of form factors -- many of which are quite small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes they exist - they're called "trim pots":

[image]

(Image of trim pots source: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=trim+pots&ia=web )

Comment: Can you please provide a link or citation for the graphic you copied into your answer? Our policy here is to always give credit to the original source.

Comment: @Elliot, there's not much point as it's just the result of an image search so it would require ten credits for the results shown. OP has obliged, however - if the search returns the same images on the next run ... I've faced the same problem on some of my answers.

Comment: @Transistor But now the OP is aware of this site's policy and hopefully will be proactive in the future.